# Using Python Multithreading to download files in a non-blocking way

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have this function that takes in a list of order ids. For each of the order id, the code checks for its status. If the status is success, the order is downloaded, otherwise the status is checked again after ten seconds. This process continues until all the files for each order id is downloaded.

```py
def download_orders(api_key, headers, activated_orders_ids):
        def check_state(order_id):
            url = f"https://api.com/{order_id}"

            headers = {"Authorization": f"api-key {api_key}"}
            state = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()["state"]
            print(f"Order ID: {order_id} Status: {state}", end="\r")
            return state

        def get_download_link(order_id):
            download_url = f"https://api.com/{order_id}"

            headers = {"Authorization": f"api-key {api_key}"}

            response = requests.get(download_url, headers=headers)
            return response.json()["_links"]["results"][0]["location"], response.json()["name"]

        def save_file(download_link, order_name):
            with requests.Session() as s:
                r = s.get(download_link, stream=True)
                total_size = int(r.headers.get("content-length", 0))
                block_size = 100 * 1024  # You can adjust this to your preferred block size.

                with open(f"{order_name}.zip", mode="wb") as file, tqdm(
                    desc=f"Downloading {order_name}.zip",
                    total=total_size,
                    unit="B",
                    unit_scale=True,
                    unit_divisor=1024,
                ) as pbar:
                    for data in r.iter_content(chunk_size=block_size):
                        file.write(data)
                        pbar.update(len(data))

        def download_logic(order_id):
            state = check_state(order_id)
            while state != "success":
                state = check_state(order_id)
                time.sleep(10)

            download_link, order_name = get_download_link(order_id)
            save_file(download_link, order_name)
            time.sleep(1)

        # Use multi-threading for parallel execution
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(5) as executor:
            executor.map(download_logic, activated_orders_ids)


download_orders(api_key, headers, order_ids)
```

Constraints: I can only make five API calls in total per second using my api-key. This is why I am using multi-threading with five number of workers.

The issue I am facing now is that my program gets blocked if a file writing operation is happening. That is to say when a streamed response is being written, the program is not making API calls either to test the status of the other orders or start writing another response if its status is success.

Additionally, I am still doing it sort of sync because until the top five requests are done getting processed (downloaded), my code is not processing the other orders. I want a situation in which everything (checking status and downloading) all happens at the same time for all the orders WHILE respecting the API limits I have.

I am new to multi-threading and asynchronous programming, so I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Bonus Question: Is there a way I can get this statement `print(f"Order ID: {order_id} Status: {state}", end="\r")` in the `check_state` function print the order ID and the dynamically update the status every time it's run. I checked on Stackoverflow and people suggested using `end="\r"`. However, this gives me just one statement and the order id is replaced by a new order id. This isn't what I'd like.

PS: Let me know and comment if you need more information to make this a more reproducible question.

Comment: Your job is IO-bound. How about using httpx instead of requests library to run asynchronously?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how things would look different if I use that? Are you suggesting avoiding using multithreading and instead use httpx? How will I respect API limits in that case?

Comment: There is clearly no point in having multiple simultaneous tqdm instances running.  They'll all step on top of each other.  If you remove the tqdm, do things improve?

Comment: I haven't tried removing tqdm, because I wanted to monitor the process for each order. Are you suggesting using just one tqdm for the entire thing. Let's say I have 100 orders, so I will get only one bar and as each order gets downloaded, the bar gets updated, yes?